# Generating .d.ts file for react-dropdown-tree-select.js module

Tags: reactjs, types, typescript-typings, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am fairly new to react and typescript. I have included the dropdown tree select in my project but it is missing the index.d.ts file in the @types\react-dropdown-tree-select folder. I am not really sure how to generate or make one (not sure of the contents). I tried the dts-gen, but it gives an error as "Couldn't load module "react-dropdown-tree-select". Please install it globally (npm install -g react-dropdown-tree-select) and try again." Even when I have installed it globally.

Comment: I don't see a types module for it, not everything has a .d.ts file. I recommend creating a file with `declare module 'react-dropdown-tree-select' {}` somewhere, and manually writing the type signatures as you use the module for a minimum effort bandaid. If you invest enough time in that declaration file maybe try to publish it as the @types module that is missing?

Comment: I created a file index.d.ts and added some definitions for it, but dont really know what all to add. I am able to see the main tree nodes, but there is no + sign to expand the nodes. Dont know what I am missing there.

Comment: This sounds like bug in the code - unrelated to the typings. You have to use the actual module (vs the type definition one) according to the regular javascript docs. Writing your own typescript definitions just lets the compiler agree with your code. In this type of scenario I recommend writing your code like it is regular javascript, and then addressing the compilation errors by updating your index.d.ts

Comment: I have this element:

<div className="react-dropdown-tree-select" style={{ height: 100 }}>
                <br />
                <DropdownTreeSelect
                    data={this.state.data}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />

handleChange is defined as:
    handleChange (value: any, checked: any) {
        if (value === "selectAll") this.toggleAll(checked);
    };
However I get an error on onChange as "property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<DropdownTreeSelectProps, ComponentState>"

Answer (score 0):

`react-dropdown-tree-select` author here.

Currently `react-dropdown-tree-select` doesn't have any typings, simply because no one ever created them. However, I can see how this can be important for TS users. If you'd like to submit a PR or collaborate on creating typings, I'd be glad to answer any questions you may have.

Thanks for your interest in this component.